# MySQL 5.5 Slow query unequally slow on two equal servers

Tags: mysql

I have identified a slow query running on one of our pages from the `mysql-slow.log`. This is fine, however, it is extremely slow on our production server compared to on our development server.

Both are running the same version of MySQL, ubuntu, apache etc. The difference between them is mainly that the Production server has got more memory and more cpu cores available than the development server have.

The other difference is ofcourse that the Production server has got way more traffic over multiple websites / databases than the development server.

This apart, both databases are equal on the production server and the development server. However, the slow query takes over 12 seconds on the prod, and between 2-3 seconds on our development server.

Watching `htop` on the prod server shows that we have lots of cpu capacity available and lots of memory, so it shouldn't be the load.

I am now clueless on where to continue my debugging to find out why MySQL is so slow on our prod server. Anyone got any tips?

Comment: Have you tried EXPLAIN ?https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html

Comment: @MeesKluivers The table is an exact copy on both servers, both in structure and content. Its not the fact that the query is slow that is bothering me, I know how to fix that part. Its that one server is 5 times as slow as the other.

Comment: So the execution plan is also exactly the same?

Comment: Could it be this? *The other difference is ofcourse that the Production server has got way more traffic over multiple websites / databases than the development server.* have you tried to see if production server has several queries running with a `show processlist` comand?... does `my.cnf` are exactly the same in production and development server? I supose variables such as `innodb_buffer_pool_size ` are not the same.

Comment: BTW, I forgot to add that MySQL use disk resources, so if there are a queue in database disk/partition queries will go slower than usual... Please compare statistics with an `iostat -x 10`